# Font Awesome 5 - Inversion of the icon position

Tags: css, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

Do you know a solution to reverse the position of an icon please?

[image]

I have found a solution, however I don't understand the properties.

```
-webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
-moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
-o-transform: scaleX(-1);
transform: scaleX(-1);
filter: FlipH;
-ms-filter: "FlipH";
```

I am looking for a solution simple...

```css
.fa{
font-size: 23px;
color: blue;
margin-right: 10px;
-webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
-moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
-o-transform: scaleX(-1);
transform: scaleX(-1);
filter: FlipH;
-ms-filter: "FlipH";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="subtitle-right"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>+(11)123 456 7890,</div>
```

Comment: all you need is this `transform: scaleX(-1);` you can remove the other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy solution would be to consider the styling already provided by Font Awesome (https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/power-transforms)

```css
.fa-phone{
  font-size: 23px;
  color: blue;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script  src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/js/all.js"></script>

<div class="subtitle-right"><i class="fas fa-phone"></i>+(11)123 456 7890,</div>

<div class="subtitle-right"><i class="fas fa-phone" data-fa-transform="flip-h"></i>+(11)123 456 7890,</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you mean to mirror the icon this should simply work

```
transform: scaleX(-1);
```