# Font-Awesome 5 - CSS Pseudo-elements, how to mirror/rotate icon

Tags: css, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I am using css pseudo elements to render icons ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Rakx/4633/))

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 13px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #515151;
}

a:before {
   font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
   content: "\f07a";
   display: inline-block;
   padding-right: 3px;
   vertical-align: middle;
   font-weight:900;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a href="#">This is a link</a>
```

Is there a way to rotate or mirror a icon?

Comment: why asking a question if you know the duplicate? by the way here is a more suitable duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55435476/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif, I found the duplicate after asking the question...

Comment: or maybe your question is unclear ... you asked *Is there a way to rotate or mirror a icon?* which is answered in the link I provided and also the below answers (maye they are also wrong for you ..)

Comment: there is two answers in my duplicate, one with `i` element and one with transform (exactly like the below answers)

Comment: @TemaniAfif, Then why are you linking to the wrong answer which does not fit to my question? My duplicate is fitting my question much better obviously

Comment: I grabed the first link I found when searching on my answers. I thought it would be trivial that you will check the whole Q&A since a duplicate is about everything and not only one answer.

Comment: @TemaniAfif, no, because the question is not even referencing css pseudo elements but is about the `<i>` tag way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `transform` property to rotate or mirror your icon.

Please check below code:

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 13px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #515151;
}

a:before {
   font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
   content: "\f07a";
   display: inline-block;
   padding-right: 3px;
   vertical-align: middle;
   font-weight:900;
}

a:last-of-type:before {
   font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
   content: "\f07a";
   display: inline-block;
   padding-right: 3px;
   vertical-align: middle;
   font-weight:900;
   transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a href="#">This is a link</a>
<a href="#">This is a link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to rotate the icon: `transform: rotate(45deg)`

Or to mirror it use `transform: scaleX(-1)`.